# Problemas al crear SP en Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buen dia, tengo un problema al crear un `stored procedure` en `Oracle` y tratar de guardarlo me indica que no tengo privilegios para la tabla a la que hago referencia , pero si me crea el SP 
si ejecuto el slect directamente si me trae registros pero dentro del `stored procedure` me indica que no tengo permisos.

> Ojo: ya he hecho `stored procedure`con otras tablas y si me deja
>   crearlos.
>
> Error(6,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(6,30): PL/SQL: ORA-01031: privilegios insuficientes

```html
create or replace procedure  sp_tbl_tmp_reger_adeudos
(p_cursor out SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
begin 
open p_cursor for
select  EXPEDIENTE  from sys.tbl_tmp_reger_adeudos;
end;
```

Saludos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como lo indica el colega puede ser privilegios sobre alguna tabla al momento de ejecutar el procedimiento que no tengas privilegios sobre ese procedimiento! SALUDOSSSS

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle permisos de select sobre la tabla que estas usando en el procedimiento al propietario del procedimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque parece raro es necesario asignarle permiso de select a la tabla a tu usuario. Eso debes hacerlo desde otro usuario de base de dato que tenga permisos de otorgar grants.

Desde ese usuario hay que hacer:

```
grant select on sys.tbl_tmp_reger_adeudos to TU_USUARIO;
```